# KvLang - TextInput: display a list calculated in the .py file on a new screen (a different class to what the list was calculated under)

Tags: python, binding, linked-list, kivy, kivy-language

i have a .py file and a .kv file. I am creating a kivy app that takes selected spinner values (Var 1, Var2, Var 3, Var 4) on a screen , compares them to some limitations with an algorithm and creates a list of answers which i want to display on a new screen  .
So far I can successfully select spinner values, input them into my algorithm and produce a list 'final_list' in the python shell. What i am having trouble with is how to display them on the new screen  in the kivy app.

in my .py file under the *class MainScreen(Screen):*
my calculated list is called 'final_list' and i would like 'final_list' to replace the text i have in my .kv file under the class : text: ("1st example answer \n 2nd example answer").

for example for selected spinner values Var 1=WNW, Var 2=1.2, Var 3=E, Var 4=medium...i should get a list of values [a7,a8,a10,a19,a20] on the new screen .

Any help much appreciated, Thanks, 
Mundi.

here is my M_A_I_N.py file:

```
import kivy
import numpy as np

kivy.require("1.9.1")                       # My version of Kivy

                                            # Kivy Modules
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button

                                            #Dictionary
dict={'N':1, 'NNE':2, 'NE':3, 'ENE':4,
      'E':5, 'ESE':6, 'SE':7, 'SSE':8,
      'S':9, 'SSW':10, 'SW':11, 'WSW':12,
      'W':13, 'WNW':14, 'NW':15, 'NNW':16,
      'Low':1, 'Medium':2, 'High':3}


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def print_info(self):
        value= self.weather_selection.ids.spinner_id_1.text
        live_weather = [dict[self.weather_selection.ids.spinner_id_1.text],
                float(self.weather_selection.ids.spinner_id_2.text),
                dict[self.weather_selection.ids.spinner_id_3.text],
                dict[self.weather_selection.ids.spinner_id_4.text]]

        print(live_weather)

     #Spot Lists
        a1 = [13, 15, 5, 10, 10, 13, 2, 3]
        a2 = [12, 14, 5, 10, 10, 12, 2, 3]
        a3 = [12, 14, 4, 10, 10, 12, 2, 3]
        a4 = [12, 14, 5, 10, 10, 12, 2, 3]
        a5 = [10, 12, 4, 10, 10, 12, 1, 1]
        a6 = [10, 12, 4, 10, 10, 12, 1, 1]
        a7 = [1, 16, 0.5, 2, 2, 6, 1, 3]
        a8 = [1, 16, 0.5, 2, 2, 6, 1, 3]
        a9 = [10, 12, 1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2]
        a10 = [12, 14, 1, 2.5, 4, 6, 1, 3]
        a11 = [1, 16, 1.5, 4, 2, 8, 2, 2]
        a12 = [10, 12, 2.5, 10, 4, 6, 3, 3]
        a13 = [10, 12, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3]
        a14 = [1, 16, 2.5, 10, 4, 6, 1, 2]
        a15 = [12, 14, 3, 10, 2, 8, 1, 2]
        a16 = [12, 14, 3, 10, 6, 8, 1, 1]
        a17 = [1, 16, 3, 10, 6, 12, 3, 3]
        a18 = [12, 14, 2, 10, 4, 6, 1, 1]
        a19 = [12, 14, 1, 10, 4, 6, 1, 3]
        a20 = [12, 14, 1, 2.5, 4, 6, 1, 3]
        a21 = [12, 14, 1.5, 10, 4, 6, 2, 3]
        a22 = [12, 14, 2, 10, 4, 6, 2, 3]

        allSpots = np.stack((a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9,
                             a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16,
                             a17, a18
                             , a19, a20, a21, a22))


        numberOfspots = (allSpots.shape[0])

        g = [0] * numberOfspots
        # print(range(numberOfspots))

        for i in range(22):
            if live_weather[0] >= allSpots[i][0] and live_weather[0] <= allSpots[i][1] \
                    and live_weather[1] >= allSpots[i][2] and live_weather[1] <= allSpots[i][3] \
                    and live_weather[2] >= allSpots[i][4] and live_weather[2] <= allSpots[i][5] \
                    and live_weather[3] >= allSpots[i][6] and live_weather[3] <= allSpots[i][7]:
                g[i] = 1
            else:
                g[i] = 0


        SB = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8",
              "a9","a10", "a11", "a12", "a13", "a14", "a15", "a16","a17", "a18"
            , "a19", "a20", "a21", "a22"]

        for i in range(len(g)):
            if g[i] == 1:

                final_list = SB[i]
                print(final_list)


class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WeatherSelection(BoxLayout):

    # For Spinner
    def spinner_clicked(self, value):

        print("spinner 1 {}:"
              "spinner 2 {}:"
              "spinner 3 {}:"
              "spinner 4 {}".format(self.ids.spinner_id_1.text,
                                    self.ids.spinner_id_2.text,
                                    self.ids.spinner_id_3.text,
                                    self.ids.spinner_id_4.text))


presentation=Builder.load_file("M_A_I_N.kv")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

here is my M_A_I_N.kv file

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import CheckBox kivy.uix.checkbox

Manager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    weather_selection:weather_selection
    FloatLayout: # allows us to have two widgets on one screen
        WeatherSelection
            id:weather_selection
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 15
            size_hint: 0.15,0.15
            text: "Calculate"
            on_release: root.print_info();app.root.current= "other"
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "bottom":1}


<WeatherSelection>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 100
    spacing: 100

    GridLayout:
        size: root.size
        rows: 2
        cols:4

        TextInput:
            text: "Var 1"
        TextInput:
            text: "Var 2"
        TextInput:
            text: "Var 3"
        TextInput:
            text: "Var 4"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25

            Spinner:
                text: "Select"
                values: ["S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW"]
                id: spinner_id_1
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id_1.text)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25

            Spinner:
                text: "Select"
                values: ["0.8", "0.9", "1.0", "1.1", "1.2","1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", "1.8", "1.9", "2.0", "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4"]
                id: spinner_id_2
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id_2.text)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25

            Spinner:
                text: "Select"
                values: ["N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW"]
                id: spinner_id_3
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id_3.text)


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25

            Spinner:
                text: "Select"
                values: ["Low","Medium","High"]
                id: spinner_id_4
                on_text: root.spinner_clicked(spinner_id_4.text)


<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "other"

    FloatLayout: # allows us to have two widgets on one screen

        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 15
            size_hint: 0.15,0.15
            text: "Back Home"

            on_release: app.root.current= "main"
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25
            TextInput:
                text: ("1st example answer \n 2nd example answer")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the 2 screens are in the same file, use a `global` variable so they can both access.
2. If the 2 screens are in the different file, well, to python, they are just 2 modules, so 2 approaches:

   - Python way: Use a module to share the value between the 2 screens
   - Kivy way:

     - declare a class variable at your `MyApp`
     - Then you can get the value by `app.get_running_app().your_class_variable_name`
     - Don't forget to `from kivy.app import app`

Now I add an example on how to share values across modules.
I use the python way, Kivy way is surely more easier, since you don't need a new file, but I like the separated file to hold all the shared variables, more clear.

Here is the file who holds the variable need to share:

```
# GlobalShared.py
MY_NUMBER = 0
```

Here is the main file to hold the 2 screen, since now we use `GlobalShared.py` to hold the variable, it doesn't matter whether the 2 screens are in the same file or in 2 different files, here I put them all in `main.py` just for a quick hack. You can separate them if you need.

Every screen has 3 buttons

- Read: read value of MY_NUMBER
- Change: add MY_NUMBER by 1
- Go: Go to next screen

You can see how it read the shared variable and change it while the other screen could still access and change the variable.

```
# main.py
import GlobalShared
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'I am ScreenOne'
        Label:
            id: lbl1
        Button:
            text: 'Read'
            on_press: root.press_read()
        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: root.press_change()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to ScreenTwo'
            on_press: app.sm.current = "screen_2"
<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'I am ScreenTwo'
        Label:
            id: lbl2
        Button:
            text: 'Read'
            on_press: root.press_read()
        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: root.press_change()
        Button:
            text: 'Go to ScreenOne'
            on_press: app.sm.current = "screen_1"
""")


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def press_read(self):
        self.ids.lbl1.text = "SharedVar is " + str(GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER)

    def press_change(self):
        GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER = GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER + 1
        self.ids.lbl1.text = "SharedVar is now " + str(GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER)


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def press_read(self):
        self.ids.lbl2.text = "SharedVar is now " + str(GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER)

    def press_change(self):
        GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER = GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER + 1
        self.ids.lbl2.text = "SharedVar is " + str(GlobalShared.MY_NUMBER)


class ScreenApp(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()

    def build(self):
        ScreenApp.sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name='screen_1'))
        ScreenApp.sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name='screen_2'))
        return ScreenApp.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenApp().run()
```

Comment: Hi Albert..Apologies for my delayed response. Your response was much appreciated. However, after trying to understand you answer, i am still struggling with the concept and have done many circles. Would you be able to demonstrate in my code. I believe when i see it work in my code i will understand the concept :)

Comment: Hi Albert, I cannot run your code?, i received error  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/daram/PycharmProjects/whichwave/main.py", line 3, in <module>
     from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
 ImportError: No module named 'kivy.lang.builder'; 'kivy.lang' is not a package

Comment: @Mundi Which version of kivy do you use? Seems that you are using an old version, so maybe it locates here at kivy.uix.widget.Builder, try import this. But installing the latest version is recommended https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html Follow the official docs here

Comment: Hi Albert, I am using v1.9.1, I did try your suggestion. That does solve that error , however now i have an error that HandSetApp is not defined?  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/daram/PycharmProjects/whichwave/main.py", line 72, in <module>
     HandSetApp().run()
 NameError: name 'HandSetApp' is not defined

Comment: @Mundi Sorry, didn't mention that I have updated the code, try again, it should work now

Comment: Albert, thank you very much for your help! That works great, I look forward to applying that method to my code soon. Regards :)